# How to sort a list of strings (names) alphabetical in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, sorting

I have a list of names (i.e strings) from user input, and I would like to sort them in alphabetic order

[my little project](https://glitch.com/~lelkes)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code as text in the question itself. Links can change over time, rendering the question useless for future visitors who have the same problem as you. Thanks!

Comment: Just use ```yourArray.sort()```

Comment: I'm voting this comment down as you need to search first and try to do it by yourself. Just post if you are getting any error or something and need help in that. Don't just post without trying it yourself first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is / was my first post, so I promise cure and improvement in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can  use something like this:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.sort()
```

Also you can write  your  own method:

```
sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (b > a) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
names.sort();

or

var names = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
names.sort(function(a, b){return a-b})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const player = document.getElementById('txt')
const button = document.getElementById('btn')
const team = document.getElementById('team')
const player_array = [];


function newPlayer () {
  player_array.push(player.value);
  shuffle_list();
  //paragraph.textContent.sort
  player.value = ''
  player.focus()
}

function shuffle_list () {
  player_array.sort();
  team.innerHTML = '';
  for (let p of player_array) {
    const paragraph = document.createElement('p')
    team.appendChild(paragraph)
    paragraph.textContent = p;
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', newPlayer)
```

Fixed it for you